# How to show all Windows folders in large icons

Tags: windows-10

I use Windows 10 Home and want to ask: Is it possible to make all Windows folders appear with large icons?

I tried to change it inside a folder and then go to File Explorer Options and lock it from there via `Apply to folders` but it is not clickable.

[image]

Comment: You have to chnage the settings in order to apply the changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Navigate to `C:\` and change the view settings to "Large icons"
   [image]
2. Click Options
   [image]
3. Click "Apply to Folders" on the View tab
   [image]

If this doesn't work the first time, do it again (that's what I had to do), but this time for Step #1, instead of right-clicking and going to View -> Large Icons, try clicking "Large Icons" in the File Explorer Ribbon > View > Layout > Large Icons.

After doing it twice, every folder across all my drives had the Large view.